# tar.gzファイルが解凍できません。

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

環境はubuntuです。tar.gzファイルを解凍したいのですが、できません。
以下のように試しましたが、だめでした。（ファイル名はgeckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz） 
①
tar xvzf geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
＞gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

②
tar -xfz geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz

> tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

③
file geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz

> geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/177451 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/3060)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

エラーメッセージに出ている通り、ファイルがgz形式でないのが原因です。何らかの理由でダウンロード(保存)に失敗していると思われるので、再ダウンロードしてみてください。

**エラーメッセージ**

> tar xvzf geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
>   gzip: stdin: **not in gzip format**

→ "ファイルがgzip形式では無い"

> file geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
>   geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz: **HTML document, ASCII text**, with very long lines, with no line terminators

→ "ファイルは(恐らく)HTMLファイルでテキストファイルだ"

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.24.0
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz

---

エラーメッセージは非常に重要です。英語で表示されていてもまずは機械翻訳で構わないので自分で読み解く習慣を付けることをおすすめします。