# エラーが理解できません。

Tags: python, ubuntu

私の環境はUbuntu18.10、python2.7です。私はSocial_mapperを使いたいのですが、私はpythonを試しました。 しかし、エラーが表示されました。

```
pwd
/home/ubuntu/san/social_mapper

python social_mapper.py -f imagefolder -i /home/ubuntu/san/social_mapper/image -m fast -a
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py:16: UserWarning: The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used.
  'The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used.'
[-] Error Filling out Facebook Profiles [-]
Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

[-]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "social_mapper.py", line 1112, in <module>
    peoplelist = fill_twitter(peoplelist)
  File "social_mapper.py", line 218, in fill_twitter
    TwitterfinderObject = twitterfinder.Twitterfinder(showbrowser)
  File "/home/ubuntu/san/social_mapper/modules/twitterfinder.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: social_mapper というのはこれでしょうか？ [SpiderLabs/social_mapper: A Social Media Enumeration & Correlation Tool by Jacob Wilkin(Greenwolf)](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper) どうやってインストールしましたか？

Comment: git clone https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper

Comment: 必要とされているパッケージがインストールされていないと思われます。「Getting Started」は実施しましたか？apt でインストールするものや、pip でインストールするものなど、必要なパッケージがたくさんあります。それらのパッケージはインストールしましたか？

Answer (score 0):

表示されている以下のメッセージは、動作に必要な`geckodriver`が実行PATHに見つからないため、エラーになっています。

```
Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

インストールの前提条件を満たしているかをよく確認してください。READMEにも手順が記載されています。

> **Prerequisites (前提条件)**
> As this is a python based tool, it should theoretically run on Linux, chromeOS (Developer Mode) and Mac. The main requirements are Firefox, Selenium and Geckodriver.
>
> これはpythonベースのツールなので、理論的にはLinux、chromeOS（開発者モード）、そしてMac上で動作するはずです。主な要件は**Firefox、Selenium、Geckodriver**です。
>
> (後略)

---

過去に別IDの方が`geckodriver`のインストールに関する質問がされており、そちらに[私が回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/53167/3060)しています。

- (geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.) [tar.gzファイルが解凍できません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53166/3060)

万一意図せず別IDになっている場合には、ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。

参考ヘルプ:
[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
入力しましたが、エラーがまだ発生しています。

Comment: エラーの内容は同様ですか？また、 `which geckodriver` の実行結果はどのようになりますか？